# In a betting game where the wager varies every bet - which wager should we use when the player wins

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, gambling

In a betting game, let's say a slot machine, where the player places a different wager every time he bets, we want to have a bonus feature that pops up on the screen every 1 out 20 turns (on average) and gives the player x6 times on his bet. I am trying to show that giving the player x6 times on his latest wager (the one that he bet right before the bonus appeared) is the same as giving him x6 on his average wager until that bonus appeared (average of around 20 bets). 
I am trying to find the formal way to prove it, and also, I would like to know how it changes given different number of bets (the bonus is every 20 rounds, so after 200 tries he will get around 10 bonuses).

Comment: I would think that in order for this to be true, the player would have to choose his wager randomly with identical distribution and independent of previous bets (and results). Is this something you assume to be the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Average wager until bonus is achieved or latest wager](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302618/average-wager-until-bonus-is-achieved-or-latest-wager)

Comment: Did you not ask this yesterday?

Comment: @BenCollister Hey, yes, I did. Sorry, I'm new to the site, and for some reason everyone that commented on the previous post stopped answering..

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Yes, that's exactly my assumption.

Comment: @tomschneorson Sometimes, it can take a while to get a good response - you may also find the Stats Stack Exchange useful.

Comment: It might be useful to expand your question a bit. Right now, it is difficult to really understand what you are trying to show and what your assumptions are. For example, what do you mean by "is the same as "? Maybe you could explain your thoughts in the context of an easy example with the player always betting $1$?